# linking android application to the mysql database phone and link the info as well

Tags: php, android, mysql

Hey guys im faced with a challenge of linking my localhost mysql/php when adding something in a form that form should also be linked with my android application.
ex. I have made a form for the admin whereby they could add a new bus route and it will be stored into their database using php mysql in localhost server now that new route should also be linked to my android application it should display the new route (My android application uses sqlite database so two different database here) so when users use the application when they search for new route it should also display as well

How can i go with that? any ideas please im really stuck in this 
thank you

Comment: can you post your code for connection

Comment: could i send you through email pls?

Comment: pratzz.sharma@gmail.com

Comment: i have sent you an email

Comment: instead of volley can you use json ? Do you have idea about it ?

Comment: yea but that is just text to string passing activities...

Comment: but it will play role with mysql

Comment: how? you mean i should remove volley?

Comment: yes use json. I mean that will help you a lot.

Comment: could you provide me with some useful links i can relate to?

Comment: is it possible if i could use both of them?

Comment: follow this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: It will also help you in future references. If you like it or if it is helpful to you then please upvote my comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are generally 2 approaches to follow when you want to 'Sync' your web database to your mobile database

1. **Push Notifications:** You could send a push notification to all your users, whenever a new route is added to the mysql db. When the notification is received by your app, (it's not necessary you show the notification to the user) you could just ping the server for the new route, or you can send the 'route' in the message part of the push notification if you can, and then add this new route to your sqlite database.
2. **AccountManager:** Using the [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) is the preferred method when you want to Sync your data. The AccountManager uses the SyncAdapter to Sync your apps data with it's cloud. When Android pings the servers of other apps for syncing, it pings your app's server too, and syncs your data. This method also takes care of issues like, if the internet connection was not working when it was intended to sync, so android will schedule the next sync soon.

Comment: how would you not show the notifications because when the update starts i dont want users to see the backend process but instead i want to see it being sent to the sqlite table from mysql for each new record inserted into mysql

Comment: You just don't create a notification. When a push notification is received, I assume you would be using GCM. When a message is received just do whatever you want with the message and NOT generate a notification.

Comment: what is GCM? will the users see the message or only from developers?

Comment: GCM is Google Cloud Messaging. It is one of the ways used to send push notifications. You can read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start).

Answer (score 0):

**To provide a good service**, you should take a look at a client-agnostic API architecture.

[image]

In this architecture, you have a PHP/go/whatever-written API, that can or can not be [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) (but it's reccomended), **that will provide, given a HTTP petition, the desired result.**

Using PHP in the simplest way, you should create different .php files, one for each action ( www.myserver.com/getRoutes.php, www.myserver.com/getRouteDetail?routeId=3), and **make those PHP files query the MYSQL database and return (echo) XML / JSON / Raw text.**

this should then be parsed by your mobile application, and added/updated to your SQLite database.

Comment: i already have the add bus.php that adds new bus routes into MYSQL database but there is that BARRIER of adding that new route into the mysqlite database automatically and that customers would find that new route