# How to sync SQLite database in an Android app, when the data changes on MySql Database Server

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my app, I have to consume REST API for syncing data between server and SQLite DB in app.
I have one activity like To-Do's in which all the To-Do's post on server will notify by the push notification to app. Now, lets check senario.

### Senario 1

There are  3 To Do 's on server 

 - Note 1

 - Note 2

 - Note 3

There are three To Do's on ther server and all of them are synced and stored in SQLite in the app. And only new notes are synced in the app by requesting for new notes using timestamp stored in SharedPrefs when user opens the app. But, what if  -Note 2 is altered on server(MySql DB) than,
- How to sync the updated or deleted notes in app with minimum N/W calls.
 - Can we fire push notifs(silently) to inform the app there is altered data on server, so it can be synced on next startup of the app. 
 I have search for this problem but cannot find appropriate solution.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786200/linking-android-application-to-the-mysql-database-phone-and-link-the-info-as-wel/34786584#34786584).

Answer (score 5):

There is very Good Topic in android [Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html). Its worth giving it a try. See the reference link from Android Developer website

Answer (score 3):

There are some solutions. You can use push notifications using [Parse](http://www.parse.com/), for instance, when your MySQL changes. Or you can use `JobManager` to enqueue custom synchronization tasks. I recommend you to see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlkJzgjzL0c) and check out the video project: https://github.com/yigit/dev-summit-architecture-demo

This reflects your problem very good and it is a very nice solution and, the most important, it is developed by a Google employee.

I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a server-side version:

Everytime, any note has been changed on the server, this note gets a incremented version:

> Note1 - version 1
>   Note2 - version 2
>   Note3 - version 3

App syncs with version 0:
- App gets all the notes with version > 0
- App saves alle the notes and the max version of 3 locally.

> Note2 gets changed server-side: Note2 - now version 4
>   Server pushes something to app

App syncs with (previously local stored) version 3:
- App gets all the notes with version > 3
- App updates Note2