# checking server every x minute

Tags: android

How to check the server every x minute to check if any updates happened.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sync SQLite database in an Android app, when the data changes on MySql Database Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848341/how-to-sync-sqlite-database-in-an-android-app-when-the-data-changes-on-mysql-da)

Comment: i don't think so i need a real time update not after start up the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out `AlarmManager`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

or from sdk 21 Job Scheduler 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html

cheers

Comment: `... and not background service that consume battery ?`

Comment: Job scheduler and AlarmManager are not background service that consumes battery

Comment: ...no? AFAIK, AlarmManager uses a service to survive reboots. I guess that JobScheduler does the same

Comment: but it is always there no matter you use it or not. So it is not consuming your battery additionally